# changing each vector in a list

Tags: r, list

I'm having a fundamental problem with how the `lapply` function works. I want to classify each member of each vector in a list.

My list:

```
s <- list(
  a = c(1, 20, 300), 
  b = c(1.1, 20.1, 300.1), 
  c = c(1.2, 20.2, 300.3)
)
```

My classification function:

```
classify <- function(n, peaks){
  which(abs(peaks-n)==min(abs(peaks-n)))
}
```

My peaks:

```
peaks <- c(1.27350, 20.32662, 300.02650)
```

If I `classify` s$c by itself, I get the result I expect:

```
> sapply(s$c,classify,peaks)
[1] 1 2 3
```

But when I try to classify all the vectors at once, I get this:

```
> lapply(s,classify,peaks)
$a
[1] 3 //should be 1,2,3

$b
[1] 3 //should be 1,2,3

$c 
[1] 1 //should be 1,2,3
```

Why am I getting the result that I do? And how do I get the result that I want?

Comment: Richie has some good comments. I'm still struggling to understand why `1,2,3` is the result you expect. Is `classify` intended to accept vectors for both `n` and `peaks`?

Comment: `n` should just be a number.  I had thought that `lapply(s,classify,peaks)` would work as I wished because `s<-lapply(s_as_text, as.integer)` "numericized" s_as_text to s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a style point: use`which.min` for finding the location of a minimum.

```
classify <- function(n, peaks){
  which.min(abs(peaks-n))
}
```

Second, break your code down a bit do see what is happening.

```
abs(peaks - s$a)   #3rd value is smallest
abs(peaks - s$b)   #3rd value is smallest
abs(peaks - s$c)   #1st value is smallest
```

These indicies are what gets returned from the call to `lapply`.

---

Based on your comment, I guess your problem is that `lapply` acts on each element of a vector, when you really want to call just call it once on everything, since `classify` is already vectorised.  Try this:

```
if(is.list(s)) lapply(s, classify, peaks = peaks) else classify(s, peaks)
```

Comment: thanks for the style point. So, for the second point, the issue is that my function needs to treat a vector differently. So when writing functions for processing lists, what sort of sanity checks are usually done on the input?

Comment: @dnagirl: I think the sanity check you want is just `is.list(s)`.  See my updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

how bout

```
> lapply(s,sapply,classify,peaks)
$a
[1] 1 2 3

$b
[1] 1 2 3

$c
[1] 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

`lapply(s, function(x) classify(x, peaks))` will pass each element of the list `s` as `n` in the function classify. `lapply(s, classify, peaks)` passes peaks as `n` to classify.